# SetBase with a KActor descendant does not appear to function

Tags: udk

I have a KActor descendant, which is a carging shot, kind of like in R-Type. When it starts charging, I do projectile.SetBase(Pawn) in the PlayerController where it is spawned. I've checked in the debugger, and its base is in face the pawn.

But it does not move with the pawn.

I have done this before, where I base KActors on a moving entity, and it moved with them. I must have done something differently, but I can't figure out what it was. Looking at the old code, I just did SetBase like I am now.

Any ideas where I might be going wrong?

Comment: Try setting phys_none before basing the actor.

Comment: I told you that in chat after I got the answer from the UDK forum! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that you have to SetPhysics(PHYS_NONE) before basing it. Apparently this is not necessary if you are basing it on another descendant of KActor, since they will then be handled at the same time in the Tick cycle.